# Download Orders with VAT/Tax for accounting

Tags: orders, invoice, tax, reports, vat

I can't for the life of me see how to export orders which have VAT/Tax. Is this possible?

We need a break down of orders with VAT for accounting purposes for our VAT/Tax return.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1):

I am not 100% sure if this will meant your needs completely but under `Reports/Sales/Tax` you can get a report of all the tax amounts for a given date period. This will split up the tax by rate and date but not sadly by the order.

You could also try to use `Reports/Sales/Orders` this will show you all orders for a given date range. This will give you the tax rate for each order so this could be the best way for your needs.